# case statement select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case

```
|AMNT1   |  AMNT2 |  Rank
__________________________
|  01    |      05 |     rank1   
|  05    |     10 |  rank2   
| 10     |     15 |  rank3  
___________________________
```

I need `case` statement which provide output `rank1,rank2,rank3`  when values between

`1 and 5` rank1 , `5 and 10` rank2 etc .

I have an amount table which has deptid and amount

output needed is 
deptid amount rank  where rank needs to be pulled from the rank table

How can I write a `select` query and put it to `case` statement ?

it should be dynamic ( i mean the table value can change but my `case` statement should read the latest value and provide the output)

Comment: So is this a look-up table, and you want to query some other data and add that rank flag based on comparing some value with the look-up? An example of how you want to use this would be helpful.

Comment: I don't quite understand the "dynamic" part of the question. What does it mean?

Comment: If you have an amount of exactly 5, should that be rank 1 or 2, since that value is in both ranges? You probably don't really want them to overlap like that. What about amounts of 1, or 15; or anything outside any range, e.g. 0 or 16?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `case`.  You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select (select rt.rank from ranktable rt where a.amount >= rt.amnt1 and a.amount < rt.amnt2) as ranking
from amount a;
```

You can also do this as a `join`.

Comment: thanks .. but somehow its not working for me  :( ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: What is t?

Comment: @Trevor . . . `t` is the name of the table being queried.

Comment: @PraphulViswan . . . Well, how do you intend to choose between two rows that both match the inequality conditions?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: but there is no t.amnt in the the original table.

Comment: @Trevor . . . It is whatever the value is that the OP wants to test.

Comment: Thats the main challenge ..   there is no condition to join between table where amount is stored and the table where ranks are saved :(

Comment: @PraphulViswan - yes there is - that amount needs to be between the two values in your look-up table. It would help if you included a sample query that gets an amount, and which you want to add the rank to, by editing your question (not in comments).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for below case statement:

```
select * from (select case when input_amt>AMNT1 and input_amt<AMNT2 THEN rank end  RANK
from ranktable) rnk
where rnk.RANK is not null
```

Comment: tthe input amount needs to be read from another table . I dont have a join criteria between them . I can do that in PL/SQL , I was wondering if a SQL statement can do this.  Amount_Table and Rank_Table   there is no join criteria  - thats the challenge .

Answer (score 0):

Here's one join version, with sample data in CTEs:

```
with rankings (amnt1, amnt2, rank) as (
            select 1, 5, 'rank1' from dual
  union all select 5, 10, 'rank2' from dual
  union all select 10, 15, 'rank3' from dual
),
amount (deptid, amount) as (
            select 1, 0 from dual
  union all select 2, 1 from dual
  union all select 3, 4 from dual
  union all select 4, 5 from dual
  union all select 5, 6 from dual
  union all select 6, 9 from dual
  union all select 7, 10 from dual
  union all select 8, 11 from dual
  union all select 9, 15 from dual
  union all select 10, 16 from dual
)
-- actual query
select a.deptid, a.amount, r.rank
from amount a
left join rankings r on a.amount >= r.amnt1 and a.amount < r.amnt2;
```

That gets the same result as Gordon's subquery approach:

```
    DEPTID     AMOUNT RANK 
---------- ---------- -----
         1          0      
         2          1 rank1
         3          4 rank1
         4          5 rank2
         5          6 rank2
         6          9 rank2
         7         10 rank3
         8         11 rank3
         9         15      
        10         16
```

As you can see using those comparison conditions means there uis no match for 15. You can change them:

```
select a.deptid, a.amount, r.rank
from amount a
left join rankings r on a.amount > r.amnt1 and a.amount <= r.amnt2;

    DEPTID     AMOUNT RANK 
---------- ---------- -----
         1          0      
         2          1      
         3          4 rank1
         4          5 rank1
         5          6 rank2
         6          9 rank2
         7         10 rank2
         8         11 rank3
         9         15 rank3
        10         16
```

but now there is no match for 1. If you try to get both with the equivalent of `between`:

```
select a.deptid, a.amount, r.rank
from amount a
left join rankings r on a.amount >= r.amnt1 and a.amount <= r.amnt2;

    DEPTID     AMOUNT RANK 
---------- ---------- -----
         1          0      
         2          1 rank1
         3          4 rank1
         4          5 rank1
         4          5 rank2
         5          6 rank2
         6          9 rank2
         7         10 rank2
         7         10 rank3
         8         11 rank3
         9         15 rank3
        10         16
```

you now get multiple results because of the overlapping rows. You coudl get rid of them by, for instance, keeping the 'higher' ranking when there is more than one match:

```
select a.deptid, a.amount,
  max(r.rank) keep (dense_rank last order by r.amnt1) as rank
from amount a
left join rankings r on a.amount >= r.amnt1 and a.amount <= r.amnt2
group by a.deptid, a.amount;

    DEPTID     AMOUNT RANK 
---------- ---------- -----
         1          0      
         2          1 rank1
         3          4 rank1
         4          5 rank2
         5          6 rank2
         6          9 rank2
         7         10 rank3
         8         11 rank3
         9         15 rank3
        10         16
```

But, really, you either shouldn't have overlaps; or you need to define which of the results is right. (You may not even need/want a lower bound at all, if your data will always match something; but that's a slightly different query too.)